# Joining Origin, First point, Second Point and Destination to create routes in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, origin-destination

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.
I have a table with the X,Y coordinates for 4 points along a route - 1st point, 2nd Point, 3rd Point and 4th Point. The 1st point is the origin and the 4th point is the destination.

[image: Screenshot of the table data]

The set of points each have a unique response ID. 
I need to join the four points thus created along a road network - one route for each response ID.

Comment: You need to edit your question to say what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Do you have roads dataset?

Comment: Yes, I do have a roads dataset.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your table in Excel format, you will create 4 excel files for each (lat, long) but with each file keep the response ID.

So the result it 4 tables with (resID, lat1,lon1,.....,resID,l4,lon4).

2. For each table (excel) convert it using (Excel to table) and then right click for each table to export data so the result is

point1.shp, point2.shp, point3.shp, point4.shp

These pictures is just an example (In my case just three shapefiles)

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. Then you will create network dataset with your road shapefiles [(Helpful tutorial)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm).

[image]

4. Add (Network Analayst toolbar) to your screen, choose new route.

[image]

5. from the (Network Analayst toolbar), click on (Network Analyst window).
6. from the (Network Analyst window), (Netw Right click on the stops Load location)

[image]

7. for each point shapefile add them and define the route name with your (responseID).

[image]

8. after adding all of the point shapefiles, you will see that the stops has the route name between all of the four points.
9. from the (Network Analayst toolbar), click solve, wait and here we are, your routes are created (one route for each 4 points).

My result (for the three points)

[image]

10. you can get also the directions, travel time and other feature (optional).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It is more or less working now. I am still getting an error for some of the routes, but I am unable to figure out why. The error message read - "No route for "(Response ID)" From Location 1 to Location 398." I wonder if it is because my points don't fall exactly on the road centerline?

Comment: @MaitriShah Exactly, So In this case, you can define large snap value (e.g 1 km more or less, depending on how your point will be achieved from your roads). This can be done from from (Network Analyst toolbar >> Network analyst option>> Location snap tab)

Comment: I tried the location snap tab but it didn't work. I then created new point shapefiles based on "Near" such that all points now lie on the road centerline file. However, the earlier error still shows.

Comment: @MaitriShah You should know that the routes mostly cannot take all of your points, it always depends on your roads dataset, networks dataset, and your points location.

Comment: @MaitriShah please accept the answer if it solved your problem